# Can I use lists in Prometheus / Prometheues in Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am selecting a source / device via `up{﻿instance﻿='$mac'﻿}` in Grafana from a Prometheus data source.
The Grafana variable `$mac` is a string representing the host name etc. which I generate depending on the user input from a (Postgre)SQL database.
This works. Now I want to do 2 things:

1. Use a self set label (e.g. the location of the device instead of its mac address)
2. Use a list / array of mac addresses for `instance` as well another variable for the labels in the legend.

The `vectors` mentioned on https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/ seems to be for the time values only. Basically I am searching something equivalent to `IN` in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you are trying to retrieve from a given metric `up` some array of values. This is what you do some analogy with `IN` operator in SQL.
From the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors) you can use `=~: Select labels that regex-match the provided string`. For instance, the query below uses it [here](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.expr=up%7Bjob%3D%7E%22(prometheus%7Calertmanager)%22%7D&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=up%7Bjob!%7E%22(prometheus)%22%7D&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h).

```
up{job=~"(prometheus|alertmanager)"}
```

or you can use the analog of `NOT IN`: `!~: Select labels that do not regex-match the provided string`.

```
up{job!~"(prometheus)"}
```

Then I think you can replace the values with your `$mac` variables on Grafana.